# Automatet Google Search with Powershell

Tags: powershell, web, search, cookies, google-search

I want to create a Powershell script, which performs a google search like "https://www.google.com/search?q=Test".
When I run  `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.google.com/search?q=Test"` I only get the html of the google cookie website. It is like open the browser in the "Incognito mode" and the first thing you see is the Google cookie banner which forces you to allow or denie their cookies. In the browser it isn´t a problem because I can click on accept and can go one with a google search, but obviously it is not possible to accept the cookies manually in Powershell.

I tried to run `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.google.com/search?q=Test"` but I get only the cookie banner as response.
Is there a way to perform a google search via Powershell?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Google when you do not pay for the service has limits on what features you can automate.